# How can I load the parent directory of a script as a module, without adding all of the siblings of that directory's parent directory to my sys.path?

Tags: python, sys.path

I'm hoping there's an easy answer to this question that I'm simply overlooking.

Here's the setup:

```
foo/
    __init__.py
    run.py
```

Contents of run.py:

```
import foo
```

Run the script:

```
$ python run.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "run.py", line 1, in <module>
    import foo
ImportError: No module named foo
```

The only way I can figure out to address this is:

Contents of run.py:

```
import sys
import os

path = os.path.abspath(__file__)
sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(path), "../"))

import foo
```

So that works, but the problem (if I'm not mistaken) is that this adds the parent directory of foo/ to `sys.path` and thus searches all of the sibling folders of foo/ for Python modules.

There's a case I have where I really, really don't want to do that. I just want to add a single directory as a module to my path, but I can't figure out how to just add that module *without* adding that directory's parent directory and thus every other directory beneath that parent directory.

Am I overlooking something here? Is there an easy way I can add a script's parent folder as a module?

Comment: Can you modify `sys.path`, `import foo` and then return `sys.path` to its prior state?

Comment: Erm, why is `run` means to import its own parent package?

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite see why `run` is meant to import its own parent *package*. After all, a package is just meant to be a way of collecting modules together; it's not meant to have significant functionality of its own.

> Packages are a way of structuring
>   Python’s module namespace by using
>   “dotted module names”. For example,
>   the module name A.B designates a
>   submodule named B in a package named
>   A. Just like the use of modules saves
>   the authors of different modules from
>   having to worry about each other’s
>   global variable names, the use of
>   dotted module names saves the authors
>   of multi-module packages like NumPy or
>   the Python Imaging Library from having
>   to worry about each other’s module
>   names.

Are you sure you don't want `run` to import a sibling *module*? That you can do using [relative imports](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html#intra-package-references).

Comment: I presented an oversimplified example to clarify the difficulty. In actuality, I have a project package with some packages in subfolders. I want to add the main project package to the path so it can be referenced from the subfolders. The more I think about it, the more I think I need to contain this main "project" package in a subfolder -- much the way e.g. Python packages on PyPi tend to have a top-level folder and then a subdirectory with the actual code for the package -- so that I can add the package to my sys.path without worrying about what else I'm adding there.

Comment: @jsdalton: But the *modules* can to refer to each other, even between subpackages, using dotted (relative) imports: say `foo.bar` and `foo.baz` are packages. Then the module `foo.bar.module1` can import `foo.baz.module2` using `from ..baz import module2`. Why should the modules have to import `foo`?

Comment: Good question, and I don't have a good answer -- except that I have never used relative imports. I'm used to just having a set of packages that are on my path, either because they are installed or I've added them, and then importing them by name when I need them. I think the solution for me is simply adding the parent directory of foo to my sys.path (thus making foo avaiable on it) and addressing my concerns about foo's parents by adding an additional containing folder in the hierarchy above it... e.g. I'd have foo_project/foo/ and put foo_project on my sys.path.